# how to pass multiple tablenames as a parameter to beeline hive queries

Tags: sql, linux, bash, shell, hive

Can we pass multiple table names and id fields to `beeline hive queries`?

like below:

```sql
select * from $table_name where id = $id;
```

and how do we run using `beeline`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like the example below.

`file.sql` is the script to run from beeline

```sql
SELECT color FROM ${hivevar:table}
WHERE red = ${hivevar:red} AND green = ${hivevar:green} AND blue = ${hivevar:blue};
```

set variables and run scripts from `beeline`

```sh
$ beeline -u jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000 --hivevar red="238" \
                                          --hivevar green="32" \
                                          --hivevar blue="77" \
                                          --hivevar table="db.my_table" \
-f /home/user/scripts/sql/file.sql
```